# Copy dimensions from a View to another Revit API

Tags: c#, revit-api

I'm trying to create a new plug-in on Revit 2016/2017 with the API.
The idea is to copy a set of element from small revit file to a central one to compile them.

Here is the code I'm using :

```
FilterableValueProvider provider = new ParameterValueProvider(new ElementId(BuiltInParameter.ALL_MODEL_TYPE_NAME));
FilterRule rule = new FilterStringRule(provider, new FilterStringContains(), "BY_GO", false);
ElementParameterFilter epf = new ElementParameterFilter(rule, true);
ICollection<ElementId> npText = new FilteredElementCollector(secDoc, secView.Id).WherePasses(epf).ToElementIds();
using (TransactionGroup tx = new TransactionGroup(mainDoc, "Insert " + Main._roomFile.Typology))
{
    ICollection<ElementId> pastedElements;
    tx.Start();
    using (Transaction tr = new Transaction(mainDoc, "Copy elements"))
    {
        tr.Start();
        pastedElements = ElementTransformUtils.CopyElements(secView, npText, mainView, null, new CopyPasteOptions());
        tr.Commit();
    }
    using (Transaction tr = new Transaction(mainDoc, "Move elements"))
    {
        tr.Start();
        pastedElements = new FilteredElementCollector(mainDoc, pastedElements).WherePasses(epf).ToElementIds();
        XYZ originePoint = new FilteredElementCollector(mainDoc, pastedElements).OfClass(typeof(Floor)).First().get_BoundingBox(null).Min;
        XYZ translation = extremitePoint - originePoint;
        translation = new XYZ(translation.X, translation.Y, 0);
        ElementTransformUtils.MoveElements(mainDoc, pastedElements, translation);
        tr.Commit();
    }

    tx.Assimilate();
}
```

When I use it, everything is good except the dimensions. They are inside the new document (I can get them with there id and RevitLookup) but they are hidden. If I select on of them and add a witness line the dimension is now visible again.
I tried to close and reopen Revit and place the vien on a sheet bt nothing.

Any idea ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/copy-dimensions-from-a-view-to-another/td-p/7226217) is the answer to the probleme.
It's Autodesk which have to solve it but the workaround is to create Dimensions with the reference of invisible one and then delete them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to regenerate the view I believe.

Try adding:

```
Document.Regenerate();
```